# Background Rake Task Help

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, email, rake, background-process

I would like to create a Rake task that:

1) checks a column in a table row
2) and if its value is false, sends an email with the row information, 
3) and then change the value from false to true.

Does anyone know the best way to approach this?

Answer (score -1):

Write the code to

1. checks a column in a table row
2. and if its value is false, sends an email with the row information,
3. and then change the value from false to true.

After you put this code in a rake task and launch this task

Comment: Are there examples?  Are there plugins?  How should this be approached?  Is my activity flow above substantial then? If so, why not just say that?

Comment: there are no answer than you need code it because it's specific to your case. There are not always a plugin. Sometimes you need write code

Comment: or not ask some no really question

Comment: your question can be not asking.

Comment: huh? don't understand still, please rephrase